# How to remove ESCAPE N'~ that is gets appended in linq query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
            WHERE (([Filter4].[b] LIKE @p__linq__21 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Filter4].[c] LIKE @p__linq__22 ESCAPE N''~'')) AND ([Filter4].[d] LIKE @p__linq__23 ESCAPE N''~'') AND ([Filter4].[e] LIKE @p__linq__24 ESCAPE N''~'') AND ([Filter4].[e] LIKE @p__linq__25 ESCAPE N''~'') AND (LTRIM(RTRIM([Filter4].[f])) LIKE @p__linq__26 ESCAPE N''~'')) AS [UnionAll1]
```

Above query is the sql equivalent for linq query.

Please let me know how can we remove ESCAPE N''~'' in above query?